# How to read distinct array of objects for each radio button

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ejs

I have this problem with read unique element for each radio button from the database. 
This is the data structure and what I get from the database

```
 { FormularID: 182,
   CampaignID: 14,
   FormLabel: 'Confirm',
   InputType: 'radio',
   InputDetails: 'Remind;NoReminder',
   InputPosition: 6 },
 { FormularID: 190,
   CampaignID: 14,
   FormLabel: 'Gender',
   InputType: 'radio',
   InputDetails: 'Male;Female',
   InputPosition: 6 } ] }
```

There is an input type and Input details fields and the input details field containers semi-colon separated values.
What I want to do is , read each radio input type and split the associated input details and render it in the html view 
**So for example 
radio Gender will only have Male and female option
radio confirm will have remind and NoRemind option to it.** 
I have tried with this code but , I only get the data all in one input filed. What am I missing in my code structure and logic. Any help would be appreciated.
This what I have so far.

```
for(var i in mydata.formular){
        switch(mydata.formular[i].InputType){
        case 'radio':
          var detailObj={};
          inputdetails=mydata.formular[i].InputDetails.split(';')
          for(var k=0;k<inputdetails.length;k++){
            detailObj[k]=inputdetails[k]

          } 
         radiodetails.push(detailObj)

          console.log(radiodetails)
        break;

        default:
        detailObj={}
        }
    }
```

and in my view I do this

```
<%for(var i=0; i< templateData.formular.length; i++){ %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userinput"><%=templateData.formular[i].FormLabel %></label>
                <% if (templateData.formular[i].InputType=="radio") { %>
                <div  class="option-margin-top">
                    <% for(var k=0; k<InputDetails.length; k++){ %>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input class="userinput" type="<%=templateData.formular[i].InputType %>" value="<%=InputDetails[k]%>" name="optionsRadios" ><%=InputDetails[k]%></label>
                    <% } %>
                </div>  <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I simplified a bit the template:

```
var splitInputs = _.map(inputs, function(input){
  var result = _.merge({}, input); // just to clone
  result.InputDetails = result.InputDetails.split(';');
  return (result);
});

var templateString = "<% _.each(inputs, function(input) { %>" +
    "<div class='form-group'><label><%= input.FormLabel %></label>" +
      "<% _.each(input.InputDetails, function(option) { %>" + 
      "<label><input type='radio' name='<%= input.FormLabel %>' value='<%= option %>'><%= option %></label>" +
      "<% }); %>" +
    "</div><% }); %>";
```

If it works for you, you can add your classes and structure.

As a side note, when you use functional programming, and specifically lodash, prefer each/forEach over index based loops (for(i = ....)). See the difference in our templates.

Now if I understand the "all in one input" problem, it has to do with the name group. Inputs of type radio are grouped by the name field. Since you used a static name (optionsRadios), they are all grouped together. To separate them, I gave each item its own name (I used the FormLabel, but you might want to use some other distinctive field). This solves the problem.

You can find a [working jsbin that generates the text here](http://jsbin.com/jupizu/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: Your solution looks good but somehow, its quite not clear how to fit this in my situation. Maybe I am not getting the understanding right. But I am still trying to understand.

Comment: okay. Can you provide a sample of the final result? Meaning, a sample html that will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it , somehow. I sent the data to the view and on each radio option, I do the split there and assign the data to the input.

```
<%for(var i=0; i< templateData.formular.length; i++){ %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userinput"><%=templateData.formular[i].FormLabel %></label>
                <% if (templateData.formular[i].InputType=="radio") { %>
This where I get the input and spit in EJS and loop through to assign the values
                <% var RadioValues = templateData.formular[i].InputDetails.split(';') %>
                <div  class="option-margin-top">
                    <%  for(var k=0; k<RadioValues.length; k++){ %>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input class="userinput" type="<%=templateData.formular[i].InputType %>" value="<%=RadioValues[k]%>" name="<%=templateData.formular[i].FormLabel %>" ><%=RadioValues[k]%></label>
                    <% } %>
                </div><% } %>
```

Comment: Meir. Thank you for your help. I appreciate your effort a very much and also the clue you gave me about radio name. It never came into my mind. I also got to know lodash from you. Thank you